# Devolver un texto en pantalla al seleccionar un option de un select

Tags: javascript, dom

Ejercicio:

Utilizando un formulario que pida: Nombre, edad, ciudad y pecado digital (copy/paste sin leer, hackear la cuenta del pololo/a, crackear software propietrio, ataque DOS, Formatera sin respaldar, etc), escribir en el documento la c penitencia personalizada en base a una matriz predefinida.

Lo que tengo:

```
 <form action="#" method="post" id="formulario">
    <p>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" size="40" id="nombre"></p>
    <p>Edad: <input type="text" name="edad" size="40" id="edad"></p>
    <p>Ciudad: <input type="text" name="ciudad" size="40" id="ciudad"></p>
    <label for="pecado">Seleciona un pecado digital:</label>

    <select id="pecado" name="pecado">
        <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccione su pecado</option>
        <option value="2">Copy/paste sin leer</option>
        <option value="3">Hackear la cuenta del pololo/a</option>
        <option value="4">Crackear software propietrio</option>
        <option value="5">Ataque DOS</option>
        <option value="6">Formatear sin respaldar</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="pecado_digital()">
</form>

<h2>Tu pecado digital es:<p id="su__pecado" style="color:red"></p>
<h3>y su penitencia es : <p id="penitencia"></p></h3>
</h2>

<script>
    function pecado_digital() {
    
        var pecado = document.getElementById("pecado");
        var selected = pecado.options[pecado.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("su__pecado").innerHTML = selected;

        for(i = 0 ;  i <= selected; i++){
            if(selected = pecado[1]){
                document.write("<p> Su penitencia es: Inventa tu propio texto. </p>");
            }else if(selected = pecado[2]){
                document.write("<p> Su penitencia es: Preguntale directo a ella o el </p>");
            }else if(selected = pecado[3]){
                document.write("<p> Su penitencia es: Instalar un programa de software libre </p>");
            }else if(selected = pecado[4]){
                document.write("<p> Su penitencia es: Leer un libre sobre hacking etico </p>");
            }else if(selected = pecado[5]){
                document.write("<p> Su penitencia es: Deberas volver hacer todos los trabajos </p>");
            }else{
                alert("debes seleccionar al menos un pecado");
            }
        }

    }

 
</script>
```

Comment: Este mensaje en la pantalla te refieres a un alert, un mensaje donde?

Comment: en el documento por ejemplo : tu penitencia es : color el resultado segun el option del select seleccionado .

Comment: Esta es una comunidad de Pregunta - Respuesta Seba, ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Que si tu codigo funciona? ¿Que si hace lo que te estén pidiendo en el ejercicio?

Comment: no se si lo estoy haciendo bien

Comment: @SebaLagos, por favor mejora tu pregunta indicando fallos o cuestiones que te estén impidiendo lograr el objetivo, por que colocar *no se si lo estoy haciendo bien*, no nos dice nada, la haría lucir basada en opiniones y podría generar su cierre

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mostrar en el documento un texto según un option seleccionado de un select](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/393933/mostrar-en-el-documento-un-texto-seg%c3%ban-un-option-seleccionado-de-un-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He editado un poco tu archivo html y js dándole un poco mas de estilo y cambiando algunas variables, dime si te sirve y si no entiendes algo.

```js
function pecado_digital(){

        //Identificamos los campos
        let nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value;
        let edad = document.querySelector('#edad').value;
        let ciudad = document.querySelector('#ciudad').value;

        let resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado');
        let pecado = document.getElementById("pecado").getElementsByTagName('option');

        let selccion=document.getElementById("pecado");
        let select = selccion.options[selccion.selectedIndex];



        //Vemos que los campos esten completos y si lo estan imprimimos esos datos
        if (nombre===''||edad===''||ciudad==='') {
            resultado.innerHTML="Por favor complete todos los campos!";
        }else{
            var result = `Hola ${nombre}, veo que tienes ${edad} años y vives en ${ciudad}.`

            resultado.innerHTML = result;


                for (i = 0; i <= pecado.length; i++) {
                    if (select == pecado[1]) {
                        resultado.innerHTML = result + `
                                <p> Tu pecado seleccionado es: ${pecado[1].text}. </p>
                                <p> Su penitencia es: Inventa tu propio texto. </p>`
                    }
                    else if (select == pecado[2]) {
                        resultado.innerHTML = result + `
                                <p> Tu pecado seleccionado es: ${pecado[2].text}. </p>
                                <p> Su penitencia es: Preguntale directo a ella o el </p>`
                    }
                    else if (select == pecado[3]) {
                        resultado.innerHTML = result + `
                                <p> Tu pecado seleccionado es: ${pecado[3].text}. </p>
                                <p> Su penitencia es: Instalar un programa de software libre </p>`
                    }
                    else if (select == pecado[4]) {
                        resultado.innerHTML = result + `
                                <p> Tu pecado seleccionado es: ${pecado[4].text}. </p>
                                <p> Su penitencia es: Leer un libre sobre hacking etico </p>`
                    }
                    else if (select == pecado[5]) {
                        resultado.innerHTML = result + `
                                <p> Tu pecado seleccionado es: ${pecado[5].text}. </p>
                                <p> Su penitencia es: Deberas volver hacer todos los trabajos </p>`
                    } else {
                        resultado.innerHTML = "Selecciona al menos un pecado"
                    }
                }

        }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body><br>
    
    <div class="container shadow"><br>
        <form action="#" method="post" id="formulario">
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="autor">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="edad">Edad</label>
                <input type="number" id="edad" class="form-control"> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ciudad">Ciudad</label>
                <input type="text" id="ciudad" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pecado">Seleciona un pecado digital:</label>
                
                <select id="pecado" name="pecado" class="form-control">
                        <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccione su pecado</option>
                        <option value="2">Copy/paste sin leer</option>
                        <option value="3">Hackear la cuenta del pololo/a</option>
                        <option value="4">Crackear software propietrio</option>
                        <option value="5">Ataque DOS</option>
                        <option value="6">Formatear sin respaldar</option>
                </select>

            </div>

            <input value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="pecado_digital()">
        </form><br><hr>

        <h2 id="resultado"></h2>

        <br>
    </div>

<script src="prueba.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Y el problema a resolver cuál era?

Comment: Por lo que he entendido , necesitaba que devuelva dos textos en base a una opción seleccionada . Me gustaría saber si pude resolver su problema . A esperar la respuesta del usuario

Comment: estoy probando y entendiendo el codigo

Comment: Cumplió con lo que necesitabas?